# zoom_changed only triggers once in Google Maps API version 3 using MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use the MVC objects in Google Maps version 3. What I can't seem to figure out is why my `zoom_changed` method is only invoked once. When I first load the map the `zoom_changed` method is invoked. But not when I zoom on the map.

```
function MarkerWidget (options) {
    this.setValues(options);
    this.set('zoom', this.map.zoom);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            icon : this.icon,
            mouseOverIcon : this.mouseOverIcon,
            orgIcon : this.orgIcon
    });

    marker.bindTo('map', this);
    marker.bindTo('position', this);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', this.onmouseover);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', this.onmouseout);
}

MarkerWidget.prototype = new google.maps.MVCObject();
MarkerWidget.prototype.zoom_changed = function () {
    $.log(this, new Date());
}
```

Shouldn't the map object fire the zoom event and notify all objects that has "this.set('zoom', this.map.zoom)"?

Comment: Found the solution, you need to specify a bindTo not set! ie. this.bindTo('zoom', this.map);

Comment: I'm glad you solved it. You may want to post that as an answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. Se my comment on the original post.

**Referenced comment below:**

Found the solution, you need to specify a bindTo not set! ie. this.bindTo('zoom', this.map);